# Generalizing a function to merge a set of Haskell pipes Producers

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I am working with the [Haskell pipes package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.0).

I am trying to use [pipes-concurrency](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency) to merge a list of Producers together.

What I want to arrive at is:

```
merge :: MonadIO m => [Producer a m ()] -> Producer a m ()
```

so given a producer s1 and another producer s2: r = merge [s1, s2]
which would give the behaviour:

```
s1 --1--1--1--|
s2 ---2---2---2|
r  --12-1-21--2|
```

Following the code in the tutorial page I came up with:

```
mergeIO :: [Producer a IO ()] -> Producer a IO ()
mergeIO producers = do
    (output, input) <- liftIO $ spawn Unbounded
    _ <- liftIO $ mapM (fork output) producers
    fromInput input
  where
    fork :: Output a -> Producer a IO () -> IO ()
    fork output producer = void $ forkIO $ do runEffect $ producer >-> toOutput output
                                              performGC
```

which works as expected.

However I am having difficulty generalizing things.

My attempt:

```
merge :: (MonadIO m) => [Producer a m ()] -> Producer a m ()
merge producers = do
    (output, input) <- liftIO $ spawn Unbounded
    _ <- liftIO $ mapM (fork output) producers
    fromInput input
  where
    runEffectIO :: Monad m => Effect m r -> IO (m r)
    runEffectIO e = do
        x <- evaluate $ runEffect e
        return x
    fork output producer = forkIO $ do runEffectIO $ producer >-> toOutput output
                                       performGC
```

Unfortunately this compiles but does not do all too much else. I am guessing that I am making a mess of `runEffectIO`. Other approaches to my current `runEffectIO` have yielded no better results.

The program:

```
main = do
    let producer = merge [repeater 1 (100 * 1000), repeater 2 (150 * 1000)]
    _ <- runEffect $ producer >-> taker 20
  where repeater :: Int -> Int -> Producer Int IO r
        repeater val delay = forever $ do
            lift $ threadDelay delay
            yield val
        taker :: Int -> Consumer Int IO ()
        taker 0 = return ()
        taker n = do
            val <- await
            liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Taker " ++ show n ++ ": " ++ show val
            taker $ n - 1
```

hits `val <- await` but does not get to `liftIO $ putStrLn` thus it produces no output. However it exits fine without hanging.

When I substitute in `mergeIO` for `merge` then the program runs I would expect outputting 20 lines.

Comment: Does it work better if you use a push-based pipe? That is, `>~>` instead of `>->`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `MonadIO` is not sufficient for this operation, `MonadBaseControl` (from [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control)) is designed to allow embedding arbitrary transformer stacks inside the base monad. The companion package [lifted-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base) provides a version of `fork` which will work for transformer stacks. I've put together an example of using it to solve your problem [in the following Gist](https://gist.github.com/snoyberg/9500916), though the main magic is:

```
import qualified Control.Concurrent.Lifted as L
fork :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadIO m) => Output a -> Producer a m () -> m ThreadId
fork output producer = L.fork $ do
    runEffect $ producer >-> toOutput output
    liftIO performGC
```

Note that you should understand what happens to monadic states when treated this way: modifications to any mutable state performed in the child threads will be isolated to just those child threads. In other words, if you were using a `StateT`, each child thread would start off with the same state value that was in context when it was forked, but then you would have many different states that do not update each other.

There's an [appendix in the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/monad-control) on monad-control, though frankly it's a bit dated. I'm just not aware of any more recent tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be your use of `evaluate`, which I assume it is the `evaluate` from `Control.Exception`.

You seem to be using it to "convert" a value inside the generic monad `m` into `IO`, but it doesn't really work that way. You are just obtaining the `m` value out of the `Effect` and then returning it inside `IO` without actually executing it. The following code doesn't print "foo":

```
evaluate (putStrLn "foo") >> return ""
```

Maybe your `merge` function could take as an additional parameter a function `m a -> IO a` so that `merge` knows how to bring the result of `runEffect` into `IO`.

Comment: Is it possible at all to create a function of the type `MonadIO m => m a -> IO a`?

Comment: In particular, here's an example `newtype ReaderIO r a = ReaderIO { runReaderIO :: r -> IO a }` with `instance MonadIO ReaderIO where liftIO io = ReaderIO $ \_ -> io`. This example makes it clear that we can't "escape" the `IO` action in `ReaderIO r` unless we provide an `r` first. This behavior is specific to `ReaderIO` and cannot be generalized over all `MonadIO`s.

Comment: @DannyNavarro Not in isolation. I meant something like `merge :: (MonadIO m) => (m () -> IO ()) -> [Producer a m ()] -> Producer a m ()`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't fork a `Producer` with a `MonadIO` base monad (or any `MonadIO` computation for that matter).  You need to specifically include the logic necessary to run all other monad transformers to get back an `IO` action before you can fork the computation.